# MYSQL update error but i dont see the error

Tags: mysql, sql

I cant see anything wrong in the code:

```
UPDATE customer_stores 
   SET long = '153.037285', 
       lat = '-27.564' 
 WHERE customer_id = 2638
```

The fields I am trying to fill are VARCHAR(100).

Comment: Why do you think it is error if you don't see some?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Preferably just the four digit number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LONG` is a [MySQL reserved keyword.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)  Enclose it in backticks to use it as a column or table identifier:

```
UPDATE customer_stores SET `long`='153.037285', lat='-27.564' WHERE customer_id=2638
```

Comment: @OMGPonies _Congratulations, you've earned the `[golfclap]` badge. Visit your profile..._